# issue with invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python

I was asked to write a program that accepts from the user 10 and only int and positive numbers (bigger than 0), and prints the maximum.

I wrote a lot of programs that gave me the maximum number from those 10 the user inserts, but when i entered negative numbers it also gave me the max of them, something that is wrong, and when i put float numbers, it comes with an error

```
invalid literal for int()with base 10
```

Any suggestions to write a correct program?

Comment: Can you show us your code? Like, the code you've already written? And what do you want to do if the user inputs negative numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The "invalid literal" error is int()'s way of saying "I don't understand what you typed".
the int() function only understands numbers (in different bases/counting systems by the way, see the [python int() doc](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)).

If you want to 'protect' agains users typing in comma-numbers, wrap it like so:

```
int(float(userinput))
```

This will first make the user-input into a fractional-number, then into an int.
Beware that [float()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#float) is picky about "," vs. "."

```
float("3.4") # gives 3.4
float("3,4") # throws "ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 3,4"
```

The test if the number is negative can come afterwards by checking the parsedNumber >= 0
It is mathematically perfectly valid to ask for 'the highest number of -1, -2 and -3', so the python built-ins won't do that for you. You have to add that criterium by hand (see also @AlexChumley's answer.)

```
max(-1, -2, -3)
```

returns -1, the 'highest' number, where 'highest' means 'closest to positive infinity'

Comment: +1 more in depth than I was willing to go due to the quality of question

Comment: thanks; I agree on quality, but I went the extra mile in hope the documentation-links are a good teaching resource :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that does what you're asking. However, you are a bit unclear on what you want to code to do in the case of negative or non-integer input. I just threw an `Exception`:

```
def find_max(my_list):
 for x in my_list:
   if x<0 or type(x) != int:
     raise Exception("You must input positive integers!")
 print max(my_list)
```